# par(xpd=NA) does not work when axes=F in R plot

Tags: r, image, plot

I want to plot an image in between two plots on one device. Importantly, the image has to be in the exact center, thus overlapping both plots. Please see the example, where I used the [R logo](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png) as image:

```
# png and grid are both for plotting the image
library("png") 
library("grid") 
Rlogo <- readPNG("Rlogo.png")

par(mfrow=c(1,2), xpd=NA) # two columns, xpd should permit plotting outside of margin
barplot(-(1:10), horiz=T, border=NA, axes=FALSE)
grid.draw(rasterGrob(Rlogo, x=unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"), width=unit(0.1, "npc"), height=unit(0.1, "npc")))
barplot(1:10, horiz=T, border=NA, axes=F)
```

results in a cut R logo:

[image: R logo gets cut]

maintaining the looks, i.e. without axes, a workaround is to add an axis with col="white":

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), xpd=NA)
barplot(-(1:10), horiz=T, border=NA, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, labels=F, col = "white")
# axis(1, labels=F, tick=F) # does not help
grid.draw(rasterGrob(Rlogo, x=unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"), width=unit(0.1, "npc"), height=unit(0.1, "npc")))
barplot(1:10, horiz=T, border=NA, axes=F)
```

which returns what I want

[image: plot with logo]

but doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Why is the logo cut in the first plot? What do axes have to do with margins / size of device / xpd?

Do you have other ideas or solutions how to achieve the logo (uncut) in the center without axes in the plots?

Comment: Not much. Logo is still cut and adding a 'white' axis to the second barplot solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that the "traditional and grid graphics are fighting each other for control of the clipping region," from a [list email from Paul Murrell](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-June/108358.html). He suggests adding `grid.clip()` before the grid command, as follows. The `xpd` is no longer needed.

```
library("png") 
library("grid") 
Rlogo <- readPNG("Rlogo.png")

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(-(1:10), horiz=T, border=NA, axes=FALSE,)
grid.clip()
grid.draw(rasterGrob(Rlogo, x=unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
          width=unit(0.1, "npc"), height=unit(0.1, "npc")))
barplot(1:10, horiz=T, border=FALSE, axes=F)
```

I can't really explain how adding the axis changes the behavior though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest my favorite classical method (without grid).

```
library("png") 
Rlogo <- readPNG("Rlogo.png")

par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(2,2,2,2))
barplot(-(1:10), horiz=T, border=NA, axes=FALSE)
barplot(1:10, horiz=T, border=NA, axes=F)

par(mfrow=c(1,1), new=T, mar=c(2,2,2,2))
plot(0,0, type="n", axes=F, ann=F, asp=1)  # flat mar and asp=1 are important to keep size ratio. 
a <- 0.3                                   # now the center is c(0, 0)
rasterImage(Rlogo, - a / 2, - a * 7 / 8 / 2 , a / 2,  a * 7 / 8 /2 )  # R logo is 800 x 700
                   # xleft,     ybottom,      xright,     ytop
```

[image: plot]