# How to plot image outside plot area with par(xpd=T)?

Tags: r, plot, clip

In R, I'm trying to plot an image outside the plot area (as a legend). However, it seems that `par(xpd=T)` or `par(xpd=NA)` just don't work.

Here's a minimum reproducible example from the error, producing the following graph.

```
par(mar=c(4,4,4,4),xpd=F)
plot(1:2,1:2)
x <- c(2,2.1)
y <- seq(1.1,1.9,len=10)
m <- matrix(seq(0,1,len=10),ncol=10,nrow=2,byrow=T)
par(xpd=T)
image(x-.2,y,m,add=T)
image(x+.05,y,m,add=T)
par(xpd=NA)
image(x-.2,y,m,add=T)
image(x+.05,y,m,add=T)
```

[image: R plot image bug]

Both colored bars should have the same width, but of course the right-hand bar is being clipped, different from what the help from `par` says:

> xpd
>
> A logical value or NA. If FALSE, all plotting is clipped to the
>   plot region, if TRUE, all plotting is clipped to the figure region,
>   and if NA, all plotting is clipped to the device region. See also
>   clip.

Is this a bug, or am I doing anything wrong?

I'm using R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe", Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit), with RStudio Version 1.1.447, in Debian Stretch.

Comment: I think it's related to `image()` not `par()`, because functions like `text()` actually work. Here is a solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37659204/2563804

Comment: @hplieninger Can you provide your solution as an answer, please? Because I'm not using `grid`, and I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly speaking, I have no direct answer to your question. I'm pretty sure it's related to `image()`, because `xpd = TRUE` works fine for other functions like `text()`.

Here are two more or less hacky solutions that worked for me with your MWE and hopefully help with your actual plot:

```r
x <- c(2, 2.1)
y <- seq(1.1, 1.9, len = 10)
m <- matrix(seq(0, 1, len = 10),
            ncol = 10, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

# Solution 1: useRaster = TRUE
par(mar = c(4, 4, 4, 4), xpd = TRUE)
plot(1:2, 1:2)
image(x + .05, y, m, add = TRUE, useRaster = TRUE)
# text(x + .05, y, "foo")

# Solution 2: grid.clip() plus image() twice
par(mar = c(4, 4, 4, 4), xpd = TRUE)
plot(1:2, 1:2)
image(x + .05, y, m, add = TRUE)
grid::grid.clip()
image(x + .05, y, m, add = TRUE)
```